How to test a class with dynamic data?
I need to write a unit test for a function that compares the content of a site with previous content. To do this, you need to change the behavior of the object that collects the necessary data, but the object is final.
public class PageBets {
    ...
    final private ParserBets parser;
    private TreeSet<Event> events = new TreeSet<>();

    public PageBets(String uri) throws MalformedURLException, URISyntaxException {
        try {
            ...
            this.parser=initParser();
            this.events = refreshEvents();
        } catch (URISyntaxException | MalformedURLException e) {
            log.debug("Not correct format link: {}", uri, e);
            throw e;
        }
    }

    public TreeSet<Event> refreshEvents() {
        lastTryUpdate = new Date();
        TreeSet<Event> refreshEvents = parser.getEvents(this);
        if (refreshEvents.isEmpty() || this.events.isEmpty()) return refreshEvents;
        refreshEvents = refreshEvents.stream()
                .filter(event -> !this.events.contains(event)).collect(Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new));
        if (!refreshEvents.isEmpty()) {
            lastNewAdd = new Date();
            sendMessageNewEventsToLog(refreshEvents);
            this.events.addAll(refreshEvents);
        }
        return refreshEvents;
    }
}

You need to change the behavior of parser.getEvents, but the object is final and therefore it doesn’t seem to work here. Should I write a proxy? or are there other options?

In general, start by considering how you might need to redesign this class to make it more testable.  Pass the parser into the constructor instead of just calling initParser.  Pass in a supplier of the time.

parser interface, implementation varies depending on the page. And if you take it outside of this class, you get a lot of duplication. Do you think this is normal?

Yes, absolutely.  Use dependency injection.
